How to Remove BLT Dependency from a Drupal Site on Acquia Cloud Before Support Ends?
Our Drupal website has been hosted on Acquia Cloud for a while, but with BLT support ending by the end of 2024, we need to eliminate our reliance on BLT.
How can we achieve this transition?
Use Cases: Are there any examples or use cases where others have successfully removed BLT from their Drupal projects on Acquia Cloud?
Solutions: Has anyone faced a similar issue and implemented a solution? What steps or best practices were followed?
Any guidance or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated!
I have follow the instructions given on the following link - https://dev.acquia.com/tutorial/you-dont-need-blt-acquia-cloud
but after the changes, the deployment pipeline has not been executed on the cloud.

What have you tried? Does this have to do with programming or configuration?

This is related to the configuration. I have used the drupal recommended setting plugin to replace the PLT and updated the pipelines.yml file as suggested in the following article -  https://dev.acquia.com/tutorial/you-dont-need-blt-acquia-cloud
Now- what should I do to trigger the post code update actions i.e clearing cache, import configs etc.

If this has to do with the configuration of the service offered by the platform, and not with a programming problem or related to a programming problem or that can be solved by programming, I am not sure that your question is within the topics of the website.

@FranciscoIALover It's not about the programing.
You can look at the link to get idea - dev.acquia.com/tutorial/you-dont-need-blt-acquia-cloud

If you are on Acquia cloud next environment. Then the tutorial you mentioned says that you do not need the hooks in your code.
But if you are on multisite environment, then make sure that you add "Post code update" script in the hooks folder in your code. Create a script file post-code-update.sh  and place in your /hooks/common/post-code-update folder.
You script file should contains the post deployment actions:
site="$1"
target_env="$2"
source_branch="$3"
deployed_tag="$4"
repo_url="$5"
repo_type="$6"
if [ "$target_env" != 'prod' ]; then
    echo "$site.$target_env: The $source_branch branch has been updated on $target_env. Clearing the cache."
    drush @$site.$target_env cr
else
    echo "$site.$target_env: The $source_branch branch has been updated on $target_env."
fi

